# SqlProvider: when doing group by store other columns in the result

Tags: f#

Lets say I have a table that has Column1, Column2 and Column3. I am grouping in the result by Column2 and would like to have following return object:
{ Key = Column2, Items = List of Column3 }

I know how would I do that in C#, but unable to get similar results in the F#. This is what I've got so far:

```
type sql = SqlDataProvider<Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER, connectionString>
let ctx = sql.GetDataContext()


let res = 
    query{
        for row in ctx.Dbo.Table1 do
            groupBy row.Column2 into g
            select (g.Key, g, g.Count())
    }
```

but when I try to access what is saved in g it looks like empty.

This is how I can do it C# way:

```
let res = 
    query{
        for row in ctx.Dbo.Table1 do
            select row
    } 

res.ToArray().GroupBy( fun (x) -> x.Column2 ).Select( fun (x) -> AnonymousObject<_,_,_>(x.Key, x.Select( fun (g) -> g.Column3).ToArray(), x.Count())).ToList() |> printfn "%A"
```

Comment: What do you mean it looks empty? Can you show the output of `res |> Seq.toList` for example.

Comment: That's not `C# Way`. You use LINQ-to-Entities in both cases. The first example uses query syntax, the second method chaining. It's the same in C#: You can write `from row in ctx...` and `ctx.Dbo.Table.GroupBy()...` in the second.

Comment: Second, what you wrote is *not* equivalent to the first query. You are calling a *database*. `GROUP BY` does *NOT* return individual rows. You loaded *everything* in memory, then usen LINQ to Objects to bundle the objects into groups.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I know these queries are not equivalent and I know that it is loading everything in memory for the second query and then starting to do transformations I need. I am trying to figure out how I can do such transformations using query syntax and load in the memory only what I need. Basically I am trying to achieve same thing what I was able achieve in 2nd query but use query syntax only.

Comment: @AlexanderM `{from row in ctx.Dbo.Table1.ToArray() ...}`. Query and method syntax are directly equivalent. If you have to load everything in memory with one, you have to do the same with the other.

Comment: `only what I need` And yet, your desired results *are* all rows - `g` is a grouping that contains *all* rows in the group. What do you want? Only the count or all rows? If you wanted only the key and count, you should use `select (g.Key,g.Count())`. This would generate a `SELECT KEY, COUNT(*) FROM Table1 Group By Key` SQL query

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, from the g all I need is the Column3 and Column2. As you can see I ignore the Column1 and potentially do not want to bring it back from the db. In real life scenario into my result set I need to bring the data from 3 columns out of 20 so over there it would make a big difference. The only reason I was including "g" in the result set was just to show where I was able to get to.